# How to incorporate a dynamic dashboard in Lotus Notes email?

Tags: html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

## IBM LOTUS NOTES 9 SOCIAL EDITION

I'm looking for a solution to incorporate a dashboard into the body of the email in lotus notes.
This dashboard will be dynamic.
But the issue I'm facing is that lotus notes' import feature is not working if I try to import an html page.
I also tried embedding via iframes but that too was not visible in lotus notes. However the same html file was working well in the browser.
What';s the solution for this?

here is the embed code and html for one of the test dashboards which is publicly available
EMBED CODE

```
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1499420723376' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='http:&#47;&#47;vijaymadhutableau.blogspot.in&#47;'><img alt='Analysis of Shipping Cost vs Profit using Dynamic Reference ' src='http:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;YK&#47;YK3FNPRDC&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='path' value='http:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;views&#47;AnalysisofShippingCostvsProfitusingDynamicReference&#47;AnalysisofShippingCostvsProfitusingDynamicReference?:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=yes&amp;:loadOrderID=3&amp;:display_count=yes&amp;:showTabs=y' /> <param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='http:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;YK&#47;YK3FNPRDC&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='showTabs' value='y' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1499420723376');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];             vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px'; var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                  scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);         </script>
```

HTML LINK

http://public.tableau.com/views/AnalysisofShippingCostvsProfitusingDynamicReference/AnalysisofShippingCostvsProfitusingDynamicReference?:embed=y&:loadOrderID=3&:display_count=yes&:showTabs=y

Comment: What version(s) of Lotus Notes are you working with?

Comment: Hey Rich. I'm using IBM Notes 9 Social Edition